# Adding charset to static file header in Jetty

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, embedded-jetty, static-files

I am building a web application, and I have to handle international characters (with stuff like "J'ai surveillé des élève à la rôtule"). Some of the data is in arbitrary static text file that are in an arbitrary directory on the file system. Those files are all utf-8 (thanks standardization!)

To serve this data, I am using an embedded jetty, with the ResourceHandler handler. I don't have any web.xml file. In addition to the static, I have a bunch of restful API that get handled trough servlet.

Problem is, Jetty ResourceHandler class doesn't seem to send a charset along with the static file `Content-Type` . If I request index.html,  `Content-Type` is `text/html`. To correctly handle accentuated character, I would like for it to be `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

For file that have a default charset of utf-8 like `text/html` or `text/css`, this is fine, but some text file dont have one and get wrongly interpreted as `Windows-1252` and the accented character get garbled (I just got a *QuÃ©bec Liquor Store* back, instead of *Québec Liquor Store*). Is there a way to specify a default character set and tell jetty to always send it? Something like apache `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hardcoding everything to UTF-8 is wrong.

How about just specifying the extension to mime-type mapping for those files you want to control?

```java
MimeTypes mimeTypes = resourceHandler.getMimeTypes();
mimeTypes.addMimeMapping("txt", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: Indeed, this is much more configurable. Worked like a charm.